# Hierarchical dictionary

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary

I need to keep questions and the answers in dictionary. Key is a number of question. I think that a value should be hierarchical, cause I need to keep a text of question, a picture and a dictionary with 4 answers(a key is the text of answer, and value is bool - whether answer is true or false).
I managed to write only this, but it doesn't keep a text of question and picture.

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<RadioButton, bool>> questions = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<RadioButton, bool>>();
```

In `RadioButton` I keep a text of answer.

Comment: I dont think you should use a dictionary here.

Comment: How about `List<Question>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you create a class for your question and encapsulate your logic inside of it and store all the necessary information about your question ?

```
class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Answer1 { get; set; }
    public string Answer2 { get; set; }
    public string Answer3 { get; set; }
    public string Answer4 { get; set; }
    public string CorrectAnswer { get; set; }

    public Image Image { get; set; }

    // add more properties if necessary
}
```

Then have a `Dictionary<int, Question>`